# How do I place the return of my IEnumerable into my StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable, stringbuilder

I am attempting to add the contents of an IEnumerable to a StringBuilder as it works its way through a file, or files. Currently my controller has two methods.

**Method 1** provides a way for me to find the chunk of data that I want to extract from a file:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetData(string fileName, string startLine, string endLine)
{
    var found = false;
    foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(fileName))
    {
        if (line == startLine) found = true;
        if (!found) continue;
        yield return line;
        if (line == endLine) break;
    }
}
```

**Method 2** is my action result in which I call the `IEnumerable` and try to add it to my `StringBuilder`.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, fileName);
string startLine = "foo";
string endLine = "bar";
StringBuilder blog = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string file in files)
{
    var blob = GetData(file, startLine, endLine);
    foreach (var item in blob)
    {
        blog.Append(item);
    }
}
var test = blog; //used to test
```

If I step through using my VS debugger I can see that `Method 1` is being hit and that it reads through the lines when it is called. However, `blog` remains empty both inside and outside of the `foreach` loop.

How do I put the contents of `IEnumerable<string> GetData()` into my `StringBuilder`?

Comment: So when you set a breakpoint to the line `blog.Append(item)`: what is in item?

Comment: Works for me. Maybe your `startLine` is not contained in the file that you read.

Comment: Seems ok to me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CE9bOk

Comment: @KlausGütter blog.Append(item) is null

Comment: You mean `item` is null? Should not happen with your code.

Comment: That is the odd part about all of this. I am looking at the same code that @aquinas has in the editor. Its null and nothing prints out

Comment: @thatguy if that was the case I would not be able to see it read through the file from the start line. but I can when I step through

Comment: @KlausGütter the (item) is the output of GetData. So the chunk

Comment: @thatguy it's working its just very slow with large files

Comment: I am not getting a null reference error nor am I getting a null error. The application is slow when ran against large text files. I am trying to make it faster.